# Apache: Changing Allow and deny to Require

Tags: apache, require, httpd.conf

I am required to change what's written below to use the *Require* directive instead, however I am unsure if i am doing it correctly. I am still very early in the learning phases, and unsure exactly how everything works.

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mywebsite>
Order Allow, Deny
Deny from all
Allow from atlanticferries.com
</Directory>
```

My rewritten version is:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mywebsite>
<RequireAll> 
Require host atlanticferries.com
</RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

I have also thought of writing it like this using RequireNone instead:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mywebsite>
<RequireNone> 
Require not host atlanticferries.com
</RequireNone>
</Directory>
```

If it were to be written with Require, is this how it would be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

RequireAny and Requirenone tags are for more complex situations in which more Require directives are involved.

What you need is:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mywebsite>
    Require host atlanticferries.com
</Directory>
```

or to deny:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mywebsite>
    Require not host atlanticferries.com
</Directory>
```

or to an ip range of 10.20.0.0/16 (just an example).

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache/htdocs/mywebsite>
    Require ip 10.20
</Directory>
```

etc.

The purpose of the change to a single Require statement is to simplify things, not to complicate them more.

For more detailed description and examples, check Require docs [Require documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)